# Every input is serializing on form submit PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Whenever I press the submit button on my form it just serializes in the url, the thing here is that I dont have any script/function included to make this happens.

I've another register form that uses ajax but this one is fine, the serialize works as it should.

my script:

```
$("#frmCadastro").submit( function() {

    dataString = $("#frmCadastro").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cadastroUsuario.php",
        data : dataString,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(retorno) {
            $("#resposta").html(retorno);
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

Just to mention, I've got 1 registration form that works well and another that I'm programming and this one is giving me headaches. I didn't even include the script and whenever I press submit all the inputs just serialize in the url, but if I put a destination on the action of the form when I press submit the destination is executed.

I think that's it, if you guys want more details just ask.

Comment: if this is a php question, where's the php code?

Comment: serialize uses elements with name="myfield" not ids, so if you don't have name="" on your inputs, it won't pick them up. See this: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: This sounds like the default behavior of a form when you don't prevent the default action.

Comment: @rncrtr Thanks for the explanation, but i've already know that, i mean, he catches all inputs and serializes them in the url the way it should... but i didn't even included the ajax file to make this happens... maybe is like Kevin B said... on submit it's normal to serialize all inputs in url... like this ? formCadastroCliente.php?inputNome=&inputSobreNome=&inputTelefone=&inputEndereco=&inputRG=&inputCPF=&inputCEP=&inputCidade=&inputBairro=&inputRua=&inputEstado=&
Sorry for the delayed "answer" problems with isp

Comment: If your form tag has the method="GET" it will serialize everything. Setting it to method="POST" should stop that, if you haven't tried it. Also, if you want to prevent the form from submitting itself (to let the ajax run first) just put in a return false; statement inside the function. Then after the AJAX runs, if you want, you can submit the form again with a $('formname').submit(); just like you have already. Hope this helps.

Comment: @rncrtr thanks for the quick answer, I'll try that tomorrow(cuz is 00:10) and I'll be back to tell if that worked... again sorry for bad english

Comment: @rncrtr Thx dude, worked like a Charm .... in fact, thanks for all those who helped me ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as an answer: If your form tag has the method="GET" it will serialize everything. Setting it to method="POST" should stop that, if you haven't tried it. Also, if you want to prevent the form from submitting itself (to let the ajax run first) just put in a return false; statement inside the function. Then after the AJAX runs, if you want, you can submit the form again with a $('formname').submit(); just like you have already.